# File upload functionality - ASP.NET MVC/AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to implement a file(s) upload functionality using ASP.NET MVC and AJAX. I would basically like to give the user an option to select single/multiple files to upload, show a summary of selected files and finally upload them to the server.

Are there any plugins/libraries that I can use? Something similar to jQuery UI - Accordion etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The Upload component in the Telerik library is pretty good.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for something that is open source(free) and non flash because the user base is not guaranteed to have Flash installed on their systems. Any recommendations there?

Comment: Telerik's ASP-MVC is non flash and has an open source (free) option.

Answer (score 1):

There are many jQuery-based plugins with Ajax feature. I think every one could be embedded into your asp.net mvc app. Here are several of them: http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/

The Accordion plugin is not for upload files, it's just for compact showing of information.

Comment: I am looking for something that is non flash because the user base is not guaranteed to have Flash installed on their systems. Any recommendations there?

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with Flash. It's JavaScript based library.